# Is it a wise decision to email graduate professors my provisional certificate of bachelor's degree?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters

I am a prospective MS student. I am considering emailing graduate professors expressing my interest to work as research assistants under the professor's supervision.  Now I have a provisional certificate (no statement of expected date of result publishing) of my bachelor's degree, and I will get the main certificate of my bachelor's degree in the month of May or June. But the application deadline for graduate program is March and April. Is it a wise decision to email graduate professors my provisional certificate of bachelor's degree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't include it in the initial email. The initial email should just be a few sentences where you show that you know what kind of work they do, and try to convince them that you have something interesting to add to the group. I would attach a short CV with your predicted graduation date, but not the provisional certificate.

Comment: I have already completed my all coursework and exams of bachelor's degree and waiting for the final result.How should I write this to the professors?  @johanna

Comment: @ShamirulIslam Exactly like you wrote it here.

Comment: In case of submission of education documents to the university,will the university be convinced with the bachelor's provisional certificate?Doesn't it affect on admission decision?However I will get main bachelor's certificate before the university starts its program on September.@Johanna

Comment: @ShamirulIslam When you first make contact with the professor, the official documents do not matter. If you manage to convince a professor to take you on, then you will have to send any official documents you have to the university to be verified. This comes long after first contacting the professor.